# Trouble using floats to mimic a table layout with different-sized objects

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create a table-less layout using floats, but I'm having trouble getting small objects to float on both sides of larger objects. Is this possible?

Here's a visual of what I'm trying to do:

[image: How can I get the blue boxes on box sides of the pink box?]

**UPDATE:** I'd like to be able to add new blue boxes and pink boxes at any time and anywhere in the document, and not have to apply custom floats to individual items...

I've saved the actual code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TuZfm/

If you prefer to see the raw code, here it is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    width:100px;
    margin:2em auto;
    }
.box {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    }
.box-medium {
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    background-color:pink;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box-medium"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
        <img class="box"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Here's what I get when I try inline-block:

[image: inline-block]

It's almost perfect except for the deadspace beside the pink box... I'd like to have two rows of blue boxes beside the pink box.

Here's the code I used when trying inline-block: http://jsfiddle.net/QCAFM/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to add new elements on the fly, you should consider using a javascript solution for this problem.

Here's a good one.
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: I don't think there's a pure HTML and CSS solution, so I'm picking jessegavin's answer. Thanks to everyone for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

float: right on the small boxes, and float: left on the large one. Worked here

Comment: Thanks, Ark. I forgot to mention this, though: I'd like to be able to add new blue boxes and pink boxes at any time and anywhere in the document, and not have to apply custom floats to individual items...

Comment: is it dinamic content or stactic? if its dynamic you can make 2 different loops making the box-mediun ones came first, if not, just put the box-medium ones on the first lines.

Comment: It would be static content that I'd be updating occasionally... Regarding your reply: "float: right on the small boxes, and float: left on the large one." This would mean the pink boxes would always be on the left, correct?

Comment: yep, just put then on left w/o changing the float;

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using display: inline-block; instead of floats? Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Inline-block is almost perfect, but it's not letting the blue boxes stack, so it creates deadspace whenever there's a pink box. I'm adding an image to the original post to show what I mean.

Comment: I think to accomplish what you want you will have to use a table or JavaScript along with absolute positioning. Unfortunately there's no way to set rowspan and/or colspan from CSS so you can't use more semantically correct elements with display: table/table-row/table-cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of absolute positioning on the pink box (taking the box out of the flow, so it won't affect the floating blue boxes), and jQuery (to add the necessary space).
This solution will only work however, if the pink box is the 3rd child.

http://jsfiddle.net/yjmdz/

EDIT: this seems to be working only on Chrome, I'm still figuring out what's happening..