# Position:absolute within floated list of elements: unexpected behaviour

Tags: css

I was working on a jsfiddle in an attempt to provide an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592774/trouble-using-floats-to-mimic-a-table-layout-with-different-sized-objects), but ran into some unexpected behaviour.

- I have a list of floated boxes (`float:left`), flowing over multiple lines.
- If I add `position:absolute` to a box on the first line, it stays in its position (as expected), but only in Chrome (not FF).
- If I add `position:absolute` to a box on second/third/... line, the box is positioned outside the containing div. If I `add top:0` and `left:0` to this box, it is positioned in the top left corner of the containing div. This happens in all browsers.

As I have no idea how to explain/fix this behaviour, I was wondering if anyone else had an idea what's going on?

http://jsfiddle.net/hdX4w/

Comment: It gets even more confusing when you remove `float` and use `display: inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/hdX4w/1/

Comment: @MyHeadHurts actually the inline-block kind of solves the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yjmdz/5/ - However, I continued working on this solution, and inserted some divs with jQuery to reposition the blue blocks, but now I'm facing another problem: even though the pink block has absolute positioning, its position is affected by the div that's inserted before it. Strange things happening today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hdX4w/9/) experiment, the elements are being positioned to the top of the wrapper as expected, but they are moving "after" the floated elements, which are all positioning to the left as they should. In other words, the absolute is making them become "last" in the list because of the float left.

It seems to do the opposite with `float: right` as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdX4w/10/).

Somehow, the float positioning (in the left scenario) is making the absolute element that is "out of flow" be pushed after the floats and this is pushing the elements "outside" your box when the width is 100px. Note how with less elements the absolute just falls in behind the floats, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hdX4w/13/).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It seems like Chrome is showing some buggy behaviour here (check http://jsfiddle.net/hdX4w/9/ in Chrome).

Comment: However, I just discovered another oddity: works as expected with img, but not with divs: http://jsfiddle.net/yjmdz/7/

Answer (score 0):

I posed the original question you're referring to (and I think I'm going to have to use a table to solve it)... Anyway, I think the reason you're seeing unexpected behavior in your example is because I used img tags to create the boxes... If you add "display:block" to all the boxes (both the small and medium ones) in the CSS, it starts behaving as expected.